# Is it possible to write single query on two table which are not connected to each other?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have two tables, I am wondering whether is it possible to write a single query on  these two table  but they are not connected to each other?

some sample code snippet whould be great helpful for my understanding.

Table: `Payment`

```
Payment_id  Payment_status  amount
1  1001          201            400
2  1002          403            450
3  1003          204            460
```

after running query : `SELECT Payment_status FROM Payment  GROUP BY Payment_staus`

it gives me result like :

```
Payment_staus
1 201
2 403
3 204
```

I have one more table named `status_code` as

```
  code    description
1 201     In progress
2 403     Complete
3 204      On Hold
```

In above query I want Payment_staus and their respective description , the result should look like this

```
   Payment_status  description 
1    201            In progress
2    403            Complete
3    204            On Hold
```

Comment: It's called a [join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)). If you are still stuck after reading up on joins, post some information about your two tables and the information you are after and we can help you out.

Comment: @MrE - But the question says the two tables are unconnected. `@user1221355` Please provide example data and desired results.

Comment: but how to write query since they doesn't share any relationship

Comment: @MartinSmith it wasn't clear what "not connected to each other" meant here. But yes, OP: example data/results needed.

Comment: What does this mean "unconnected". Aren't all database tables unconnected?

Comment: table one named Booking having feild booking_id and status_code ; table two named Status_code having field s_code and description ; I want to write query for staus_code mapping to description.

Comment: Why doesn't `status_code` in `Booking` join to `s_code` in `Status_code` - Or does it? Please provide some example data.

Comment: Sigh...that's a standard join OP.

Comment: @BD, pretty sure we all saw that one coming

Comment: I think in this case "unconnected" means there isn't a foreign key but there should be. :-\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Cartesian join (note there is no JOIN condition). All possible combinations of records are in the results:

```
tableA (charfield Char(2))
tableB (numberfield Number(1))

INSERT 'A' INTO tableA;
INSERT 'B' INTO tableA;
INSERT 1 INTO tableB;
INSERT 2 INTO tableB;

SELECT * 
FROM   tablea CROSS JOIN tableb
```

Results:

```
charfield|numberfield
=====================
A        |1
A        |2
B        |1
B        |2
```

Comment: If you're going to write a cross join in your code, I highly recommend you state your intentions explicitly (using the `CROSS JOIN` operator) so that your peers know that it was on purpose and that you didn't forget a where clause or the comma is in there by mistake and tableb was meant to be an alias... anyway I am highly doubtful that the result of a cross join is what the OP is after in this case.

Comment: Added cross join. Based on last comment by OP I think you're right.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT p.payment_id, p.Payment_status, s.description
FROM Payment p
JOIN status_code s
ON p.Payment_status = s.code
```

This uses a SQL 'join' to connect the two tables on the status_code table's code property.

This will give you results like

```
Payment_id   Payment_status   description
1001         201              In progress
1002         403              Complete
1003         204              On Hold
```

Comment: OP specifically said the two tables have no relation, so there's nothing to join on.

Comment: +1 Based on current state of comments looks like this could be what they need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a UNION query, but the field types/column counts in both sub-queries must match:

```
SELECT a, b, c
FROM table1

UNION

SELECT p, q, r
FROM table2
```

The alternative is simply doing a full cartesian join, which can return HUGE result sets if the two tables have a large number of rows - you'll be getting `n x m` rows